# No redirecciona una página con PHP después de ingresar registro

Tags: php, mysql, redirección

Tengo este código que funciona bien en local con `XAMP` pero al hacer pruebas en hosting gratuito no redirecciona la página donde se encuentran los mensajes y otro formulario, se queda en la página de registrar factura con el mensaje "registro guardado". Cuál sería el posible error...

Código:

````
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
 

 include '../conexion2.php';

 if(isset($_POST['register'])){
 
     if(strlen($_POST['nombre']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['direccion']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['telefono']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['combo']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['estado']) >= 1){


         $nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);
         $fecha = date("y/m/d/H/i/s");
         $direccion = trim($_POST['direccion']);
         $telefono = trim($_POST['telefono']);
         $pais = trim($_POST['combo']);
         $estado = trim($_POST['estado']);
         $usuario = trim($_POST['user_login']);
         $OK = trim($_POST['OK']);

                    
         $consulta = "   INSERT INTO apost_ventas(nombre,fecha,direccion,telefono,pais,estado,user_login,liquidado) 
                         VALUES ('$nombre','$fecha','$direccion','$telefono','$pais','$estado','$usuario','$OK')";

         $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
         
         if($resultado){
             header('location:https://servicorreo.000.webhostapp.com/apostillas/apost_agregar_producto.php?mensaje=guardado')
             ?>
             <h3 class="ok">Registro guardado</h3>

             <?php                                
         } else {header('location:https://servicorreo.000.webhostapp.com/apostillas/apost_agregar_producto.php?mensaje=falta')
             ?>
             
             <h3 class="bad">Registro no guardado</h3>
             
             <?php
            } 
         } else {header('location:apost_agregar_producto.php?mensaje=nada')
             ?>
             
             <h3 class="bad">ingrese los datos</h3>
             <?php 
     }
         
 }
    
?> ```
````

Comment: La redirecciones deben ser a una URL externa? No son a tu mismo sitio?

Comment: Gracias al mismo sitio,

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa, es que estás redireccionando a una ruta en la que no se exactamente que es lo que estarás haciendo, pero enseñas la misma vista que en caso de que falle, cambiando el mensaje. Imagino que lo que tu estás viendo es el mensaje que estás escribiendo, en este caso guardado.

Simplemente tienes que cambiar dicha redirección al sitio en el que quieras. Puedes hacer mediante **php** o con la ayuda de **JavaScript**

**EJEMPLO PHP**

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
 

 include '../conexion2.php';

 if(isset($_POST['register'])){
 
     if(strlen($_POST['nombre']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['direccion']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['telefono']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['combo']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['estado']) >= 1){


         $nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);
         $fecha = date("y/m/d/H/i/s");
         $direccion = trim($_POST['direccion']);
         $telefono = trim($_POST['telefono']);
         $pais = trim($_POST['combo']);
         $estado = trim($_POST['estado']);
         $usuario = trim($_POST['user_login']);
         $OK = trim($_POST['OK']);

                    
         $consulta = "   INSERT INTO apost_ventas(nombre,fecha,direccion,telefono,pais,estado,user_login,liquidado) 
                         VALUES ('$nombre','$fecha','$direccion','$telefono','$pais','$estado','$usuario','$OK')";

         $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
         
         if($resultado){
             header('location:https://midominio/redireccion') // Añade aquí el sitio
             ?>
             <h3 class="ok">Registro guardado</h3>

             <?php                                
         } else {header('location:https://servicorreo.000.webhostapp.com/apostillas/apost_agregar_producto.php?mensaje=falta') // También podrás modificar esta ruta
             ?>
             
             <h3 class="bad">Registro no guardado</h3>
             
             <?php
            } 
         } else {
             header('location:apost_agregar_producto.php?mensaje=nada') // Y esta, para que te redireccione donde desees
             ?>
             
             <h3 class="bad">ingrese los datos</h3>
             <?php 
     }
         
 }
    
?>
```

**EJEMPLO JAVASCRIPT**

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
 

 include '../conexion2.php';

 if(isset($_POST['register'])){
 
     if(strlen($_POST['nombre']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['direccion']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['telefono']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['combo']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['estado']) >= 1){


         $nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);
         $fecha = date("y/m/d/H/i/s");
         $direccion = trim($_POST['direccion']);
         $telefono = trim($_POST['telefono']);
         $pais = trim($_POST['combo']);
         $estado = trim($_POST['estado']);
         $usuario = trim($_POST['user_login']);
         $OK = trim($_POST['OK']);

                    
         $consulta = "   INSERT INTO apost_ventas(nombre,fecha,direccion,telefono,pais,estado,user_login,liquidado) 
                         VALUES ('$nombre','$fecha','$direccion','$telefono','$pais','$estado','$usuario','$OK')";

         $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
         
         if($resultado){
         ?>
             <script> 
             <!---- Código de JavaScript  ----->
                   window.location.replace('http://www.ejemplo.es'); 
         
             </script>
             
             <h3 class="ok">Registro guardado</h3>

             <?php                                
         } else {header('location:https://servicorreo.000.webhostapp.com/apostillas/apost_agregar_producto.php?mensaje=falta') // También podrás modificar esto con javaScript
             ?>
             
             <h3 class="bad">Registro no guardado</h3>
             
             <?php
            } 
         } else {
             header('location:apost_agregar_producto.php?mensaje=nada') // Y esta lo mismo, para que te redireccione donde desees
             ?>
             
             <h3 class="bad">ingrese los datos</h3>
             <?php 
     }
         
 }
    
?>
```

Te recomiendo solamente redireccionar en caso de registro, y en caso de que falle, sigas pasando el mensaje, para que el usuario pueda ver que es lo que ha fallado. Yo personalmente utilizaria la versión del php.